# What does it mean for g and h to be indendent in pedersen commitments?

Tags: commitments

I'm looking at a [research paper](https://s68aa858fd10b80a7.jimcontent.com/download/version/0/module/7833162361/name/PIT2.pdf) about the insecurity of a specific (wrong) usage of Pedersen commitments.

First, I'll go through the steps of Pedersen commitments, so that it can be shown if I have a basic misunderstanding.

**My understanding of Pedersen commitments**

Firstly we say Bob wants Alice to commit to a message, therefore he generates two prime numbers `p` and `q`.

p <--- random prime
q <--- random prime

Bob then generates the generator `g`, which is of the order of `q` and is in the group $Z_{p}^*$.

g <--- $\in Z_{q}^*$

He then picks a secret value `x` in $Z_{q} $:

x <--- $\in Z_{q} $

x is the secret key, which he uses to derives the public key:

$h = g^{x} mod p $

Alice now wants to commit to a specific message, and has access to the public key and secret key of bob.
She first picks the message `m` and a random integer `r`, and then computes her commitment `c`:

c = $ g^{m}*h^{r}$

Alice can now send the commitment to Bob.
When Alice wants to reveal her commitment, she sends `m` and  `r``to Bob. Bob is now able to do the same computation and compare.

**Application in voting, and issue of independence**

In the article referenced earlier, the scheme is used to confirm the integrity of a set of shuffled votes.
In this context, a list of `n` encrypted votes are denoted by $ m_{1},...,m_{n} $.
The pedersen commitment for a list of votes is then computed by:

$ c = G_{1}^{m_1} ... G_{n}^{m_n} * H^{r}$

And then the paper says this about the values of `G` and `H` (there may be some notation confusion, since I am used to using lowercase g and h for the generator for generator and PK, while the paper opts for capital letters).
But then the paper states the following issue that may arise:

*"If independence is violated between H and one single value Gi, then the extended commitment c can be open for any vector of alternative messages m′1,..., m′n. If this happens, then the whole shuffle proof argument collapses, i.e., it is possible to construct a fake proof for an incorrect shuffle"*

I'm a little bit confused as to what it means for the values of $G_{i}$ and H to be "independent", and what it likely means when we have several versions of `G`, so I have two questions:

**1**

if we have n G's, then does that mean that the group that we are working in needs to have n generators?

**2**
How can there be one H, and several generators? if `H` is computed by using `G`, then which `G` is used to compute the public key `H`. Maybe I am misunderstanding something basic about the construction outlined in the paper?

Comment: You might want to fix the link to the paper - to get to a link on your harddrive, we'd have to break into your system, and we're not supposed to admit we can do that...

Comment: embbarasing! fixed it!

Comment: You sure that's the right paper?

Comment: oh geez, it's the german version, sry again

Comment: It's still a final report about a public penetration test (run by the Swiss) on a voting system - it doesn't mention anything about Pedersen...

Comment: Now the right one is up! sry

Answer (score 2):

> I'm a little bit confused as to what it means for the values of $G_i$ and $H$ to be "independent",

Actually, the paper gave a fairly decent definition:

> Independence means that respective discrete logarithms $h = \log_G H$ and $g = \log_H G$ are unknown to everyone.

That is, no one is supposed to know the solution $x$ to $G^x = H$

However, because we're working with multiple generators, it turns out that we need a stronger statement: no one knows a nontrivial solution $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n, b)$ for the relation $G_1^{a_1} \cdot G_2^{a_2} \cdot ... \cdot G_n^{a_n} \cdot H^b = 1$, where the trivial solution is $a_1 \equiv a_2 \equiv ... \equiv a_n \equiv b \equiv 0$.

However, the same idea applies.

> if we have $n$ $G$'s, then does that mean that the group that we are working in needs to have $n$ generators?

Yes.  Actually, we have a lot more - if we're dealing with a group with a size $q$ where $q$ is prime, then there will be $q-1$ generators.  Because we need $q$ to be at least 256 bits (to make the discrete log problem hard), that means that we have a *huge* number of generators available to us.

> How can there be one $H$, and several generators? if $H$ is computed by using $G$,

Actually, we don't compute $H$ using $G$, we pick it independently.

Now, if you go back to the original Pedersen paper, he did suggest that the verifier select $H$ (and hence might do that selection by picking a random value $h$ and computing $H = G^h$, and giving $H$ (but *not* $h$) to the prover); that way, the verifier could be confident that the prover didn't know the discrete log.

However, nowadays we generate $G$ and $H$ independently (so literally no one knows the relationship) - this approach obviously extends to multiple $G$ values.